# Ignoring separating character using scanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

The problem:
I am attempting to use scanf to read a sentence with fields seperate by | ,so naturally i use the scanf's natural features to ignore this symbol but it then also ignores everything that has a | in it.

The code, simplified:

```
int main(){
    char* a=malloc(8);
    char* b=malloc(8);
    scanf("%s | %s",a,b);
    printf("%s %s",a,b);
}
```

when i attempt the input:

> TEST | ME

it works as intended, but when i have the following case:

> TEST  ME|

it naturally reads the test, but ignores the ME|, is there any way around this?

Comment: `%s` doesn't do what you think it does. In general, `scanf()` doesn't do what you expect it to do either. Better use saner functions like `strtok_r()` or `strchr()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    scanf("%[^ \t|]%*[ \t|]%[^ \t\n|]", a,b);
    printf("%s %s",a,b);
```

Annotation:

`%*` : ignore this element.

E.g. `%*s` //skip the reading of the text of this one

`%[character set(allow)]` : Read only character set that you specify.

E.g. `%[0123456789]` or `%[0-9]` //Read as a string only numeric characters

`%[^character set(denied)]` : It is to mean character other than when `^` is specified at the beginning of the character set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can scan for a character set. The problem you're seeing is not related to the vertical bar, it's the fact that a string stops at the first whitespace character, i.e. the space between `"TEST"` and `"ME|"`.

So, do something like:

```
if(scanf("%7[^|] | %7[^|]", a, b) == 2)
{
  a[7] = b[7] = '\0';
  printf("got '%s' and '%s'\n", a, b);
}
```

See [the manual page for `scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for details on the `[` conversion specifier.

Comment: Interesting, I write a lot of C and didn't know this feature. Is it standarized?

Answer (score 1):

This one should work.

```
char a[200], b[200];

scanf ("%[^|]| %[^\n]", a, b);  // Use it exactly
printf ("a = %s\nb = %s\n", a, b);
```

Meaning of this formatting. I seperate the format string into 3 parts and explain.

"%[^|]" - Scan everything into 1st string, until the bar character('|') appears.

"| "    - Read the '|' and ignore it. Read all white space characters and ignore them.

"%[\n]" - Read remainder of the line into the 2nd string.

Test case

```
first string is         this | 2nd is this
a = first string is     this
b = 2nd is this

no space|between bar
a = no space
b = between bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Leading spaces can be truncated by using extra local variable to store leading spaces.

> %[ ] needs to be mentioned in scanf to store leading spaces
>
> "%[ ]%[^\n]",first_string,second_string , mentioned scanf format specifier is to  read two strings .

```
 first_string contains leading spaces from given input string
 second_string contains actual data without leading spaces.
```

Following is the sample code

```
int main()
{

  char lVar[30];
  char lPlaceHolder[30];

  printf("\n Enter any string with leading spaces : ");
  memset(lVar,'\0',30);
  memset(lPlaceHolder,'\0',30);

  scanf("%[ ]%[^\n]",lPlaceHolder,lVar);

  printf("\n lPlaceHolder is :%s:\n",lPlaceHolder);
  printf("\n lVar is :%s:\n",lVar);
  return(0);
}
```

**Input:**

> "         hello world"

**Output:**

> lPlaceHolder is :         :
>
> lVar is :hello world:

Note: Space not displayed properly for lPlaceHolder after uploading to stackover flow website

Answer (score -1):

I'd say instead of messing with `scanf()`, try using saner functions - those that work as per the (intuitive) expectations:

```
char s1[] = "FOO | BAR";
char s2[] = "FOO BAR |";

void print_sep(char *in)
{
    char *endp;
    char *sep = strtok_r(in, "|", &endp);
    printf("%s\n", sep);
    if (sep = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &endp))
        printf("%s\n", sep);
}

print_sep(s1);
print_sep(s2);
```

Comment: Work with the original program are different.